# How do I get colour with Windows command prompt using RSpec in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby, rspec, command-prompt

In other o/s RSpec returns nicely coloured results (red, green etc).

However in the windows (Vista) command prompt my text output is just plain old boring white.

How can I bring colour to my RSpec test results?

Thanks

Evolve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE:
Win32Console no longer works with rspec. ANSICON recommended.
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/487#issuecomment-3556806

Answer (score 7):

I had to install ansicon, and now everything is fine. (Even in my Aptana terminal).

Install ansicon description:
 http://qastuffs.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-install-ansicon-for-cucumber-to.html

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. Win32console didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Did you specify '--color' in your rake rspec tasks' spec_opts?
Something like this..

```
  Spec::Rake::SpecTask.new(:your_task_name) do |t|
    t.spec_opts = ["--color"]
    t.spec_files = [] # List of spec files
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `win32console` gem. BTW: which version of RSpec are you using? Every single version of RSpec I have ever used, actually prints out

```
You must 'gem install win32console' to use colour on Windows
```

when you try to colorize output.

Comment: Yeah from my web searches they seemed to imply people were getting the above message, but I have not seen the above message myself. I am running the following versions; rspec 1.2.9 and rspec-rails 1.2.9 I've installed the win32console gem, spec results are still white. Do I need to change any settings to 'turn on' colour output?

Comment: You have to pass the `--color` argument to the `spec` command.

Comment: That worked for my spec commands :)
Also tried 'rake spec' and that was in color (as I think my default spec.opts file already has color option included)

My spec.opts file is just the default of:
--colour
--format progress
--loadby mtime
--reverse

Is it possible to configure the 'spec' command to have color on by default or is that why you use 'rake spec'? (Still new to RSpec)

Comment: This was the originally accepted answer but now ANSCICON is required. Ive updated the accepted answer to help people who keep coming here looking for a solution.

Comment: Doesn't work with JRuby, fyi. I haven't been able to try it with POR on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running in Windows XP which I believe is an NT system. The ANSICON claims that this is not supported. Yes it does not work for cmd. But if you put the files in system32 folder, just run the ansicon.exe from anywhere.
Win32Console is deprecated for rspec but you may still use it for other programs you write if you want color output from the command line. see the readmes in the gem.
I put ansicon in my start>run>open text box. It works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

When using the MINGW64 bash shell provided by Git on Windows rspec displays things without any color. While this shell environment is perfectly capable of displaying ANSI color, rspec fails to detect it as a TTY. A super simple workaround is to use:

```
$ rspec --force-color
```

For example, take this boring old monochrome:
:[image: Boring old monochrome]

And make it happy with one simple command line argument:
[image: Wow, it's beautiful full color!]

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for sharing Steve.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I've been unable to get ansicon to work, as it crashes when running from cmd.

To fix I added the **Win32console** gem to my **gem file** and then ran bundle update.

**As an update: Put the gem in the test group of your gemfile:

```
    group :test do
      gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
      gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
      gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
      gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
      gem 'win32console'
    end
```

This will prevent errors when pushing to heroku

Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

The best method is to create a file name .rspec in the root folder of your app and include this single line of code in it:

`--colour`

Done and dusted

Comment: windows doesn't allow this file name