# How do i get my console to display test results in color(red/green)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, guard

Im building a ruby on rails aplication, and trying to get my TDD on.  I have the following gems installed under my testing environment.

```
turn <0.8.3
rspec-rails
capybara
guard-rspec
minitest
win32console
```

Everything seems to be playing nicely together, however, When my test run they aren't in color. Just plain white text.  Am I missing something? do I need to initialize something?

I am running on windows 7

Thanks in advance, you guys rock!

Comment: From past questions, looks like you're running Windows. Check out this answer to an identical issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733348/how-do-i-get-colour-with-windows-command-prompt-using-rspec-in-ruby

Comment: Yes, I am running windows. thanks

Comment: And you're passing the `--color` argument to `spec`?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to do this.  what file do I do that in? I'm running rspec 2.8.0, and they were running early 1.0 versions. So, I'm not sure if they file is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Win32Console no longer works with rspec.
Check this out >>>>
[Ansicon](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/487#issuecomment-3556806)

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I have colored console in Windows XP and know how colorization is performed.

Answer (score 2):

I run on OSX, but here is how I do it.  Put a file named `.rspec` in the root directory of the project with the following contents:

```
--colour
```

Try that.

Comment: I know that the pre-pending a filename with the `.` character on a unix system makes it a hidden file, is there a different file convention for windows?  Also as @michaelmichael said, try running `spec --colour some_file_spec.rb`?

Answer (score 2):

Just specify it in the guard block:

```
guard :rspec, :cli => '--color --format doc' do
```

As of RSpec Guard 4.0, you need to pass options to `cmd`,

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'rspec --color --format doc' do
```

Comment: `cli` is deprecated and replaced with `cmd` but it not longer works with these options.